# Problems creating a locked down terminal session

Tags: security, xterm

I am configuring a jump box and trying to minimize the users access to the underlying host the service runs on. I need to provide ssh access from the box, which means it requires a terminal emulator. I can provide a simple front end with zenity for the user to specify the target they want to connect to, however most modern terms provide additional functionality which exposes a shell on the underlying host, e.g. the xfce-terminal and lxterminal allow the user to open a new tab (starting a shell on the local machine), rxvt allows the user to highlight text and run it in perl.

As a jumpbox, I want to minimize the footprint of any additional applications I install (and have already spent way too much time dealing with DBus and polkit). Is there a simple way to get a minimal term running on this machine while only relying on standard repos and minimal config?

Comment: Take a look at this post https://serverfault.com/questions/242391/can-i-disable-interactive-shell-access-while-tunneling-web-traffic-through-ssh

Comment: Nope, not relevant. I'm not tunneling. I'm not using MS-Windows/putty.